# How do I get an sql*plus connection for the oracle 11db that I downloaded on my computer yesterday?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, sqlplus

Okay, this is kinda infuriating. . . I can connect to the oracle database on a server in another city but I can't connect to the oracle database on my own computer?  What am I missing?  Below is my code. . . I have even tried with both ports 1521 (and 8080 for my Tomcat server).

```
try
{
      Connection conn;

      // Load the JDBC driver
      String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
      Class.forName(driverName);

      // Create a connection to the database            
      String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost"; 

      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","password");     

 }   
 catch (IOException e) 
 {
    System.out.println("Caught I/O Exception);
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw e;
 } 
 catch (SQLException e) 
 {
    System.out.println("Caught SQL Exception);
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw e;
 }
```

}

Comment: Thanks Mitch.  I know what the tnsanames.ora file is now... cant get the right connection string without knowning what the SID is :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL you have is incorrect.  Try this:

```
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:database";
```

You have to use the right username and password and substitute the values for host and database that apply to your case.  Don't just use that string verbatim.

Is Oracle running?  Can you connect using SQL*Plus?  If SQL*Plus can't connect, Java won't be able to, either.

And the JDBC driver JAR that matches your JDK and database versions needs to be in the CLASSPATH.  You should be able to find the driver JAR in the distro you downloaded.

Don't set it using any CLASSPATH environment variables; use the `java -cp` command line argument.

Modify this code to try it out.  I know that it works.

```
package persistence;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * util.DatabaseUtils
 * User: Michael
 * Date: Aug 17, 2010
 * Time: 7:58:02 PM
 */
public class DatabaseUtils
{
    private static final String DEFAULT_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:database";
    private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "password";
/*
    private static final String DEFAULT_DRIVER = "org.postgresql.Driver";
    private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/party";
    private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "pgsuper";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "pgsuper";
*/
/*
    private static final String DEFAULT_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/party";
    private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "party";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "party";
*/

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long begTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        String driver = ((args.length > 0) ? args[0] : DEFAULT_DRIVER);
        String url = ((args.length > 1) ? args[1] : DEFAULT_URL);
        String username = ((args.length > 2) ? args[2] : DEFAULT_USERNAME);
        String password = ((args.length > 3) ? args[3] : DEFAULT_PASSWORD);

        Connection connection = null;

        try
        {
            connection = createConnection(driver, url, username, password);
            DatabaseMetaData meta = connection.getMetaData();
            System.out.println(meta.getDatabaseProductName());
            System.out.println(meta.getDatabaseProductVersion());

            String sqlQuery = "SELECT PERSON_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME FROM PERSON ORDER BY LAST_NAME";
            System.out.println("before insert: " + query(connection, sqlQuery, Collections.EMPTY_LIST));

            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            String sqlUpdate = "INSERT INTO PERSON(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES(?,?)";
            List parameters = Arrays.asList( "Foo", "Bar" );
            int numRowsUpdated = update(connection, sqlUpdate, parameters);
            connection.commit();

            System.out.println("# rows inserted: " + numRowsUpdated);
            System.out.println("after insert: " + query(connection, sqlQuery, Collections.EMPTY_LIST));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            rollback(connection);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            close(connection);
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("wall time: " + (endTime - begTime) + " ms");
        }
    }

    public static Connection createConnection(String driver, String url, String username, String password) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        Class.forName(driver);

        if ((username == null) || (password == null) || (username.trim().length() == 0) || (password.trim().length() == 0))
        {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        }
        else
        {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        }
    }

    public static void close(Connection connection)
    {
        try
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.close();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void close(Statement st)
    {
        try
        {
            if (st != null)
            {
                st.close();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void close(ResultSet rs)
    {
        try
        {
            if (rs != null)
            {
                rs.close();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void rollback(Connection connection)
    {
        try
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.rollback();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static List<Map<String, Object>> map(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException
    {
        List<Map<String, Object>> results = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

        try
        {
            if (rs != null)
            {
                ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
                int numColumns = meta.getColumnCount();
                while (rs.next())
                {
                    Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= numColumns; ++i)
                    {
                        String name = meta.getColumnName(i);
                        Object value = rs.getObject(i);
                        row.put(name, value);
                    }
                    results.add(row);
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            close(rs);
        }

        return results;
    }

    public static List<Map<String, Object>> query(Connection connection, String sql, List<Object> parameters) throws SQLException
    {
        List<Map<String, Object>> results = null;

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try
        {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            int i = 0;
            for (Object parameter : parameters)
            {
                ps.setObject(++i, parameter);
            }

            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            results = map(rs);
        }
        finally
        {
            close(rs);
            close(ps);
        }

        return results;
    }

    public static int update(Connection connection, String sql, List<Object> parameters) throws SQLException
    {
        int numRowsUpdated = 0;

        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        try
        {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            int i = 0;
            for (Object parameter : parameters)
            {
                ps.setObject(++i, parameter);
            }

            numRowsUpdated = ps.executeUpdate();
        }
        finally
        {
            close(ps);
        }

        return numRowsUpdated;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I tried the above url and it gave me the below error:java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection.

Comment: I was reading Oracles online info.  In order to set up the user name and password I entered:  SQL> create user root identified by password default tablespace users temporary tablespace temp;  Is tablespace or users my database name?  When I installed Oracle it gave me a global database at orcl.12.something or other.  I know I sound like an idiot.  It just seems like MySQL is much easier to use with JDBC.

Comment: See revisions above.  Have you done this before with MySQL?  That's good to know.  You've used JDBC successfully before; you can do it again.

Comment: Thanks to Mitch Wheats comment above and your string url example I was able to figure out the right connection string.  I NOW KNOW WHAT THE tnsnames.ora file is.  It is almost impossible to get the right connection string with out knowing your SID.  Anyway, thanks guys.

Comment: Now all I have to do is figure out why I am getting a:java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket exception??!!??